# Is it possible to call Python functions from Libre Office Calc?

Tags: python, libreoffice

Consider the following simple Python function:

```
def mysum(a, b):
   return a + b
```

I would like to put `=mysum(5, 7)` in a cell of the Calc spreadsheet, so that is simply returns the number 12.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=43686 indicates that it is possible, but not easy - you have to write a small wrapper function in libreoffice basic that calls your python script.

Comment: Duplicate http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/10219/writing-user-defined-functions-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps..
https://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html

and this page talks about integrating python 
https://sites.google.com/site/rampatilsprofile/resources/python-resources/programming-in-python-for-friends-and-relations